# Submit dynamically created form

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-forms

i am using angular 2/4 for one of my projects and i am in a situation where i have to download a file on submitting the request. I am doing currently.

```
this._http.post('url', body, { headers: urlEncodedHeader, observe: 'response', responseType: 'arraybuffer' })
            .subscribe((data) => {

                let blob = new Blob([data.body], { 'type': 'application/octet-stream' });
                saveAs(blob, 'file.zip');
            })
```

The file size could be very huge so i want the browser to handle the request instead of parsing the data and creating a blob in the application side. So i read somewhere that we can create a form element dynamically and give the handle to the browser instead of letting the application handle the blob and storing in the memory. So i tried

```
post_to_url(path, params, method) {
        method = method || "post";

        var form = document.createElement("form");
        form.setAttribute("method", method);
        form.setAttribute("action", path);

        for (var key in params) {
            if (params.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                var hiddenField = document.createElement("input");
                hiddenField.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
                hiddenField.setAttribute("token", key);
                hiddenField.setAttribute("value", params[key]);

                form.appendChild(hiddenField);
            }
        }
        document.body.appendChild(form);
        form.submit();
    }
```

This doesnt seem to be working, the page always redirects to some error page. So my query is, how to download a huge file without hanging the browser. Please help.

Comment: "...some error page...". Doesn't seem to be hell of a detailed error description.

Comment: It just redirects me to a page where it displays request failed, Grizzy 2.4.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was i was doing

```
hiddenField.setAttribute("token", key);
```

instead of

```
hiddenField.setAttribute("name", key);
```

Changing to the name solved my issue

Comment: Good solution 

Answer (score 0):

Maybe simply generate link to downloading file on `post`:

```
this._http.post('url', body, { headers: urlEncodedHeader, observe: 'response', responseType: 'arraybuffer' })
            .subscribe((data) => {

              let link = data.body; // //http://path/to/file;
              window.open(link);

              // or
            var link = document.createElement('a');
            link.href = link 
            link.click();
            });
```

Comment: Well my file size is huge ...so cant use this method .

Comment: @VikhyathMaiya, I mean after the `post` data, on the response get download file `URL`.